# PHP:getting checkbox value and text field value in on form submit

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am building form with checkbox and texfield like this

```
 $sector = [
        ['name'=>'Electrical','id'=>1],
        ['name'=>'Automobile','id'=>2],
        ['name'=>'Repairing','id'=>3],
        ['name'=>'Blacksmith','id'=>4]
    ]
?>
<?php for each($sector as $value){ ?>
  <input type="checkbox" name="work_experience_sector[]"  value=" <?php echo $value['id'] ?>">
<input type="text" name="work_experience_sector_experience[]" class="form-control border-input">

<?php }?>
```

I would like to checked category value along with experience year something like that after form submit

```
eg:
   category-1 and experience-2
   category-2 and experience-4
```

I've tried this

```
 foreach($_POST['work_experience_sector_experience'] as $key=>$value){
         echo 'category'.$_POST['work_experience_sector'][$key].'expe'.$value.'<br>';
     }
```

But the problem is not getting the values in proper order

Comment: http://prntscr.com/jmtlh8 http://prntscr.com/jmtlkc  can you recheck your code? it's work perfectly on my side.                         foreach($_POST['work_experience_sector'] as $key=>$value){
         echo 'category-'.$_POST['work_experience_sector'][$key].'AND expe-'.$_POST['work_experience_sector_experience'][$key].'<br>';
     }

Comment: add some values in the textbox in another order